# Add free product programatically to Woocommerce order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Good afternoon,
I have added code that adds, free product and calculate price, than add sale price and shows what is discount that person is getting in the end.

Below is code that I have, now I want to add this free product to order that I get in system as well as what customer get in email. I tried adding $order in order to call and add this product to order but I didn't manage to do it.

Can you help me with?

```
// Add free gifted product for specific cart subtotal
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'check_free_gifted_product' );
function check_free_gifted_product( $cart ) {
if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
return;

// Settings
$free_product_id = 24005; // CHANGE THIS TO YOUR PRODUCT ID
$targeted_subtotal = 200; // CHANGE THIS TO THE REQUIRED LOWEST CART TOTAL

$cart_subtotal = 0; // Initializing

// Loop through cart items (first loop)
foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ){
// When free product is in cart
if ( $free_product_id == $cart_item['product_id'] ) {
$free_key = $cart_item_key;
$free_qty = $cart_item['quantity'];
$cart_item['data']->set_price(23.90); // Optionally set the price to real one or to 0
$cart_item['data']->set_sale_price(0); // Optionally set the sale price to zero and show in cart how much customers discount is
} else {
$cart_subtotal += $cart_item['line_total'] + $cart_item['line_tax'];
}
}

// If subtotal match and free product is not already in cart, add it
if ( ! isset($free_key) && $cart_subtotal >= $targeted_subtotal ) {
$cart->add_to_cart( $free_product_id );
}
// If subtotal doesn't match and free product is already in cart, remove it
elseif ( isset($free_key) && $cart_subtotal < $targeted_subtotal ) { $cart->remove_cart_item( $free_key );
}
// Keep free product quantity to 1.
elseif ( isset($free_qty) && $free_qty > 1 ) {
$cart->set_quantity( $free_key, 1 );
}
}

// Display free gifted product price to zero on minicart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'change_minicart_free_gifted_item_price', 10, 3 );
function change_minicart_free_gifted_item_price( $price_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
$free_product_id = 24005; // CHANGE THIS TO YOUR PRODUCT ID

if( $cart_item['product_id'] == $free_product_id ) {
return wc_price( 0 );
}
return $price_html;
}
```

I tried adding $order in order to call and add this product to order but I didn't manage to do it.